# Error in xml file premature end of data in tag

Tags: xml, file

I took this system ever made but it does not know what it is happening!

line: 197 core.php

```
foreach ($this->getAll() as $banner) {
```

line: 191 core.php

```
$_xmlBanners = simplexml_load_file(PATH_XML."banners.xml");
```

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <banner id="1">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/l2jbr.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='list_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="2">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top100mmorpg.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="3">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/gamesitestop100.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="4">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/arenatop100.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="5">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/mmorpglist.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="6">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top200.gif</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
</list>
```

My errors retorn :

```
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: banner line 33 and list in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag banner line 26 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag banner line 19 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag list line 2 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 206
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 197
```

I am with this problem. heard of characters encoded.
something.
but how do I fix?
follows all data. if you need any more please ask me. I'm desperate. Sorry my english. was done with google!
thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of  end tags.  Load the file in a browser, and it will tell you the line number.

Below you will see the fixed xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <banner id="1">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/l2jbr.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='list_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="2">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top100mmorpg.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="3">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/gamesitestop100.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        </banner>
        <banner id="4">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/arenatop100.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        </banner>
        <banner id="5">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/mmorpglist.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        </banner>
        <banner id="6">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top200.gif</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
  </list>
```

Comment: Close your banner tag, and add a closing list tag, and this validates correctly.

Comment: It would be much better if there was an argument to ignore (and perhaps add) missing tags.

Answer (score 0):

your  `<banner id="3">` doesn't have a closing  tag.  neither do the `<banner id="4">` and `<banner id="5">` tags.

If you add closing `</banner>` tags to those, your xml will be valid

Answer (score 0):

banner elements having id 3, 4, and 5 are not closed. Please check your XML. You should close all tags.